# Automating letsencrypt with a standard apache2 setup for new certificates

Tags: lets-encrypt

I run a service which allows users to create forms that have their own domain (e.g. http://userform1.myservice.com).

I would like to use letsencrypt to provide SSL for the forms, however there is (currently) no wildcard option.

I am familiar with letsencrypt and I already have www.myservice.com secured with it.

The setup is standard apache2. Originally, the default virtualhost handled the domains, however I have updated the code to create a conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and soft link it to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for each user domain that is created.

Now I am trying to figure out how to automate the creation and installation of certificates, so that it can be done in real time when a user creates a new form.

Using `certbot-auto -d userform1.myservice.com`, the only question that gets asked interactively is whether to make it easy or secure (i.e. redirect http to https). Is there a way that I can specify this on the command line to make it completely non-interactive? Is there anything else I should do to ensure that there is no interactivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for certbot-auto](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#command-line-options) shows the command has a `--non-interactive` option:

```
  -n, --non-interactive, --noninteractive
                        Run without ever asking for user input. This may
                        require additional command line flags; the client will
                        try to explain which ones are required if it finds one
                        missing (default: False)
```